# ToggleButton's Checked event occurs before binding works

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, binding

I have a togglebutton and a checked event handler. Also, I have a two-way binding to a viewmodel's property. What I see in a debug is that I fall into the handler and then into the property's setter. The problem is that I need the correct property value for my bussines logic. This behavior seems odd to me.

Comment: The behavior is correct. You shouldn't manipulate business logic in the event. post your code and XAML

Comment: @HighCore, why is it wrong? Mvvm light has an EventToCommand behavior which is for manipulating business logic in the event, is it wrong too?

Comment: So, if you're binding Event to Command, then why do you have the IsChecked bound? you're duplicating yourself. Either do it in the setter of the VM property, or in the command.

Comment: @HighCore, hm... I think I get what you are talking about, thanks.